# Listing out all SubstitutionData in a SparkPost email template

Tags: sparkpost

Does anyone know if there's an easy way to know all the Substitution Data in a spark post email template. I am using Java but am open to any language, just want to see if the SDK or REST API's from SparkPost allow that.

The substitution data are the values you can inject into an email template, kind of like firstName, lastName, etc.

Comment: Hello @mabel-oze, do you mean using an endpoint to get all the substitution data based on template id?